# Rescaling Dataset by a constant value

Tags: derivatives, data-analysis

I have two sets of measurements that measure one thing. I would like to graph the relative heights of the measurements, however one set is nearly consistently higher than the other one.
I would like to know how to determine the constant I need to substract from the higher dataset, that minimizes the sum of the differences between each data point pair.
So I tried WolframAlpha.com and set up an equation like this:
$$
\begin{multline}
\frac{d}{dx}(|(13840-x)-8192|+|(9588-x)-6666|+|(5713-x)-3994|+ \\
+ |(12625-x)-8170|+|(22024-x)-4742|+|(10439-x)-8522|+ \\
+ |(12725-x)-12525|)=0
\end{multline}
$$

But WolframAlpha doesn't solve it since the computation times out. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

well what about

```
Minimize (|(13840−x)−8192|+|(9588−x)−6666|+|(5713−x)−3994|+|(12625−x)−8170|+|(22024−x)−4742|+|(10439−x)−8522|+|(12725−x)−12525|)
```

in Wolframalpha

Comment: hm it spits out 2922, so I guess it works.. but couldn't I just add all the differences between each data pair and divide the result by the amount of data pairs? That would be a lot easier but then I get 4877 as a result.. now I don't know which is right

Comment: If you divide the above formula by some constant the position of the minimum will not change. So either you've done something wrong, or doing something different.